# Opt in CSS Typography

Tags: sass

I am trying on my latest project, opt in typography. It's working well so far. I have my base `.typography` class below:

```
.typography
  a
    @extend .link

  i, em
    @extend .italic

  b, strong
    @extend .bold

  h1, .h1
    @extend .h1

  h2, .h2
    @extend .h2

  h3, .h3
    @extend .h3

  h4, .h4
    @extend .h4

  h5, .h5
    @extend .h5

  h6, .h6
    @extend .h6

  p, ul, ol, pre, address
    @extend .block-margins

  ul
    @extend .unordered-list

  ol
    @extend .ordered-list

  pre, code
    @extend .fixed
```

I then just apply that to the parent element of any block i'd like to be styled like that.

My problem comes when, for example, I get to a `p` that needs to be opted in and it seems a bit overkill to wrap a `<div class="typography"> ... </div` around it just to opt it in.  I would prefer to just add the `.typography` class to the `<p>` directly.

Is there any sass trickery I can use to alter my current typography class to allow it to work as is but also when I apply the typography class to any element within. So I basically need:

```
.typography
  p
    [STYLES]
```

and

```
p.typography
  [SAME STYLES]
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @cimmanon I feel the css and typography tags are required. I have removed the styling one though.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with typography.

Comment: Well if you think so. I'd appreciate it if you could add at least the CSS tag back on then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably slightly more verbose than you're hoping for on the Sass side, but its the best you're going to get:

```
%link {
  color: blue;
}

%block-margins {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

@mixin typography {
  &.typography, .typography & {
    @content;
  }
}

a {
  @include typography {
    @extend %link;
  }
}

p, ul, ol, pre, address {
  @include typography {
    @extend %block-margins;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
a.typography, .typography a {
  color: blue;
}

p.typography, .typography p, ul.typography, .typography ul, ol.typography, .typography ol, pre.typography, .typography pre, address.typography, .typography address {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it at least a but reausable and not repeat code, you should define your styles as:

```
.typography
  a
    @extend .link
  ...
```

and then add the others by using previous ones:

```
a.typography
  @extend .typography a
...
```

By doing this you'd at least have a single point of maintenance even though your styles will be *duplicated*.

Comment: Might have to go down this route. I was trying to see if there was a way using @at-root to bring the `a` for example, up tot he top level but at the same time adding `.typography` to it to make: `a.typography`.

Comment: I'm not sure as I can't test itin JSFiddle using SCSS (apparently doesn't support `@at-root` construct). But according to https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/774 you should try it but not within `a` but rather within `.typography` so you would be able to say `@at-root a&` and reuse in the same way as in my answer. If that  `a&` will work in SASS at all. AFAIK `&` can only be at the beginning unlike LESS where it can be anywhere.

Comment: The second example doesn't compile.  Sass doesn't allow you to extend nested selectors.

Comment: I ended up doing it like 'a.typography
  @extend .link' as I have my `.link` styles specified anyway so then I can extend those rather than the nested one. Will try out more snazzy sass ideas on this later and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider it a perfect solution, but one way to make it work could be to re-assign your styles:

```
p, ul, ol, pre, address {
  &.typography {
    @extend .block-margins;
  }
}
```

Might work until you find a better solution which does not produce duplicate code.

Comment: But this is then addressing only **the second scenario**... First one with nesting elements within `.typography` ancestor doesn't work any more.

Comment: Yeh, using this, wrapping elements in a wrapper with .typography on would not style them.